# how to use 'POST' API using fetch for user signIn page in react native

Tags: react-native, api, authentication, post

I want to use 'POST' API in my react native app, either I don't want to show email and password in the console.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question . What do you want to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for example, it in official documentations
https://reactnative.dev/docs/network